# Hide keyboard in ios app

Tags: ios, alert

I have problem with hide keyboard when I showed optionsSheet.

Where is the problem in my code?

```
- (void)optionsSheet2{

    if(optionsSheet2) {
        [optionsSheet2 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
        optionsSheet2 = nil;
    }

    optionsSheet2 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", nil),  NSLocalizedString(@"Delete all", nil), nil];

    [optionsSheet2 showInView:self.parentViewController.view];
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_uiSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [_uiSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [_uiSearchBar setHidden:true];
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Have you added Delegate method properly ?

Comment: can u be a bit more clear abt ur question?

Comment: i have UIActionSheetDelegate and UISearchBarDelegate

Answer (score 1):

you change code like this:

```
 - (void)optionsSheet2
    {
     [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
    }
```

Comment: chech this line code: [self.parentViewController.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: It is not working too :(
If I don't use optionsSheet its work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple Solution

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Works with UITextField, UITextView and all subviews.